# Disable TLS in angular-oauth2-oidc

Tags: angular, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am using `angular-oauth2-oidc` in my project.
The Openid (identity) provider uses self signed certificate. The Identity provider is not in our control.
When we configure the identity url and try login from angular we always get an error.

```
error loading discovery document

GET <<url>> net:: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

When we check with Identity provider team, they suggest us to disable TLS and try.
But I do not see any config to disable TLS in `angular-oauth2-oidc`

What could be the solution in such ccase?

Comment: It's not a thing that can be disabled on the javascript client-side. You can configure chrome to ignore certificate errors, or you can disable TLS in windows (those are very dangerous since it will be disabled for all invalid certificates) or you can add the certificate to the trusted publishers store In Windows.

Comment: @Eldar Yes, I agree. I am adding this certificate in Mac as trusted certificate, instead of changing anything in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to make your windows machine to trust the self-signed certificate. But this will only be on your machine.

See
[Make a Self-Signed Certificate Trusted On Windows](https://www.ntweekly.com/2020/08/31/make-a-self-signed-certificate-trusted-on-windows/)

Comment: This link is no more valid.

Comment: Fixed the url for you